# Can you clear a text form with jquery if another form is selected?

Tags: jquery

My jquery code below switches a state dropdownlist out with a state input text box depending on the country that is selected.

It also disables one another depending on which one you select, however I would like to make it not disable the other form field but instead have it clear the contents of "othstate" input box if "usstate" is selected

Is this even possible?

```
<script>

function locationlist() {
    $('#othstate').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#country').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == 224) {
            $('#usstate').val('').show().removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#othstate').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            $('#usstate').val('').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $('#othstate').show().removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will clear the contents of othstate:

```
$('#othstate').val('');
```

Comment: thanks I know that is correct because I see it in another part of a code I have but it doesn't work for me, weird

Comment: No prob. Did you try modifying your code so the line: $('#othstate').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled");
becomes $('#othstate').val('').hide().attr("disabled", "disabled"); ?